# Error taking object from HTTP Request with Slim

Tags: php, http, post, http-post, slim

I'm sending via POST to an API-REST with Slim, I receive my data but I've not been able to convert to object.
Look:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
    $request = \Slim\Slim::getInstance()->request();
    var_dump($_POST);
    print("<br>");
    print("<br>");
    var_dump($request->getBody());
```

The result is:

```
array(11) { ["nombre"]=> string(10) "nom prueba" ["apellido"]=> string(10) "ape_prueba" ["edad"]=> string(2) "20" ["altura"]=> string(3) "190" ["goles"]=> string(3) "200" ["amarillas"]=> string(2) "10" ["rojas"]=> string(1) "5" ["asistencias"]=> string(1) "4" ["partidos"]=> string(3) "100" ["equipos"]=> string(1) "3" ["trofeos"]=> string(1) "2" }

string(136) "nombre=nom%20prueba&apellido=ape_prueba&edad=20&altura=190&goles=200&amarillas=10&rojas=5&asistencias=4&partidos=100&equipos=3&trofeos=2"
```

But if I do json_decode, It is not converted to object:

```
$received = $request->getBody();
    var_dump(json_decode($received)); // NULL
```

How can I do it? What's the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request body is not in JSON format, so json_decode won't work, nor is it necessary. Your request is already converted to a PHP object, as indicated by your output of `var_dump($_POST);`. You can access the parameters such as nombre by using `$_POST['nombre']`.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that for now, but one day I read that using array POST doesn't work for compound objects.

Comment: True, but then you have to have the request body be actually in `application/json` format, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Your output shows that the data is in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Once it's being sent to your script in JSON format, then `json_decode()` will work as expected.

Comment: Yeah, I did it and It works. But I had to change some configurations in php.ini file because I had another error. I had to put " always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 ", because Slim changes in it.

Comment: In concluision, the solution was:
1) Change Content-type to application/json, in the client request and, obviously, send an JSON object.
2) Change: always_populate_raw_post_data = -1, in php.ini
3) Restart PHP.

After that, one can use with no problem:

`$received = $request->getBody();
    var_dump(json_decode($received));`